# CSS Flex - When re-sizing wrapper flex item change its width dimension

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am using CSS Flex in order to display three DIVs consequential in a wrapper.
The width dimension for the first DIV (`item0`) is to 50px.

I need to change the height of the `wrapper` and keep the original width for `item0` and `item1` DIVs inside the wrapper.

My current problem is that:

- When re-sizing the `wrapper`, item for flex (`item0`) get a different `width`. size

Please click the two buttons in the example to see the change in dimension.

I would like to know:

- Why the width size change?
- How to maintain the width size for `item0` and `item2`same as my original CSS settings?

Notes:

I understand scroll-bar appears taking space. How I could I keep `item0` and `item2` at a fix width and `item1` stretching to fill up the remaining space? (I have tried to use `%` but I cannot get the result wanted).

```js
var btn0 = document.getElementById('btn0');
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var item0 = document.getElementById('item0');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

btn0.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  wrapper.style.height = '25px';
  result.value = item0.getBoundingClientRect().width;
});

btn1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  wrapper.style.height = '350px';
  result.value = item0.getBoundingClientRect().width;
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: auto;
}

#flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

#item0 {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
}

#item1 {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 150px;
}

#item2 {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="flex-container">
    <div id="item0" class="item">a
    </div>
    <div id="item1" class="item">b
    </div>
    <div id="item2" class="item">c
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id='btn0' type="button">Smaller wrapper</button>
<button id='btn1' type="button">Bigger wrapper</button>
item0 width is: <input id="result"type="text">
```

Comment: additional jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/32579j92/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex: 0 0 50px` for the item0 style.

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32579j92/1/)

It tells the flexbox layout don't grow and don't shrink and give it a width of 50px.

It is always good to use the flex: property for flexbox items because the default value for it may be different from browser to browser.
(Actually your problem doesn't happen in firefox for example)

Comment: Is my mind playing a trick on me or does the box appear to be getting smaller, but the pixel being output is still 50px? o.O

Comment: @A.Sharma I am using chrome Version 49.0.2623.110 m on Windows7 - I don't see any visible change on the first box. Only the hole container appearance change due the scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

When the width of the container is reduced, all child elements are reduced proportionally too.

Add `flex: 0 0 auto;` to item0 and item2. It disallows element to shrink to its minimum when there is not enough space.

```js
var btn0 = document.getElementById('btn0');
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var item0 = document.getElementById('item0');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

btn0.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  wrapper.style.height = '25px';
  result.value = item0.getBoundingClientRect().width;
});

btn1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  wrapper.style.height = '350px';
  result.value = item0.getBoundingClientRect().width;
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: auto;
}

#flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

#item0 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
}

#item1 {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 150px;
}

#item2 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="flex-container">
    <div id="item0" class="item">a
    </div>
    <div id="item1" class="item">b
    </div>
    <div id="item2" class="item">c
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id='btn0' type="button">Smaller wrapper</button>
<button id='btn1' type="button">Bigger wrapper</button>
item0 width is: <input id="result"type="text">
```